# Why does current arrange itself in such a way as to minimize power loss in resistors connected in parallel?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, power, optimization

In problem 2 in [Problem Set 6](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-c-lagrange-multipliers-and-constrained-differentials/problem-set-6/MIT18_02SC_pset6.pdf), it is said:

> "Electricity prefers to flow in the way that minimizes energy loss to resistance."

Using Lagrange multipliers I was able to show that assuming the above statement, in parallel, $I_kR_k=V$, a constant, for each resistor attached in parallel. Physically, this makes sense since if we assume Ohm's law is obeyed, this result is just an immediate corollary of putting resistors in parallel: the terminals of all the resistors coincide so the potential differences across all the resistors, which are path-independent, are the same.

So my question is, is there a deeper physical reason *why* current distributes itself so that it minimizes power loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The minimum entropy production principle (MINEP)](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Minimum_entropy_production_principle#Example_B:_Electrical_networks) has been suggested as a key rule in non-equilibrium thermodynamics in steady states. The idea is that the thermodynamic fluxes ([in this case currents](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Minimum_entropy_production_principle#Example_B:_Electrical_networks)) organise themselves to minimize entropy production ([in this case indicated by power dissipation as heat](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Minimum_entropy_production_principle#Example_B:_Electrical_networks)) because the thermodynamic "forces" set themselves up to do it (basically by constrained optimization like you did for the currents).

[MINEP is not always valid](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Minimum_entropy_production_principle#Breaking_of_MINEP). It assumes a system that is relatively close to equilibrium with linear, time-independent responses. If you increase the voltage enough there will presumably be a current breaking through and frying your circuit while maximizing entropy - far from equilibrium [maximum entropy production](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Maximum-entropy-production-principle-in-physics-%2C-Martyusheva-Seleznevb/d26e8a51e1447da3c8c610f7bdef8acfe290c193) is common. There is a confusing array of results and principles here; my impression is that this field is not settled yet.